# PHP MySQL - Grouping inner join associated children of parent record

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

Currently, I have invoice items in one mysql table that reference back to the invoice number in another table. I am running a select * from query to join the two (below). My question is, how do I create a `while` inside a `while`?

With the way it currently is, I am getting multiple listings of the same invoice number for each invoice item that it contains... I just need to group them together so I get one invoice record, with the invoice children under it.

```
$result = SELECT * FROM tblinvoices INNER JOIN tblinvoiceitems ON tblinvoices.invoice_id = tblinvoiceitems.invoice_id WHERE invoice_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY AND CURDATE() ORDER BY invoice_date DESC, invoice_time DESC;


<table style="width: 100%;">
    <?php
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
        ?>
```

*** start invoice loop here ***

```
<tr> <td width="6" align='center'> <?php echo($row['invoice_id']);?>
    </td>
            <td width="6" align='center'>
                <?php echo($row['invoice_id']);?>
            </td>
            <td width="6" align='center'>
                <?php echo(date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['invoice_date'])));?>
            </td>
            <td width="6" align='center'>


        <?php echo(date("g:i A", strtotime($row['invoice_time'])));?>
        </td>


    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <table>
```

*** Start invoice items loop here ***

```
<tr>
    <td align='center'>

                <?php echo($row['invoice_item_id']);?>
            </td>
            <td align='center'>
                <?php echo($row['invoice_item_name']);?>
            </td>
            <td align='center'>
                <?php echo($row['invoice_item_cost']);?>
            </td>
            <td align='center'>
                <?php echo($row['meal_item_taxed']);?>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

*** End Invoice Items Loop ***

```
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

*** End Invoice Loop Here ***

```
<?php
}
?>
<tfoot>
```

I'm just not sure how to do the while loop when I'm already in one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have shared an example that helps you to resolve your problem. If not please share your all code so I'll help you to resolve.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .finder {
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>HELLO</td>
        <td>HELLO 1</td>
        <td>HELLO 2</td>
        <td>HELLO 3</td>
        <td>HELLO 4</td>
        <td class="clickme">HELLO 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="finder"><td>123456</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>HELLO</td>
        <td>HELLO 1</td>
        <td>HELLO 2</td>
        <td>HELLO 3</td>
        <td>HELLO 4</td>
        <td class="clickme">HELLO 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="finder"><td>356454756</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>HELLO</td>
        <td>HELLO 1</td>
        <td>HELLO 2</td>
        <td>HELLO 3</td>
        <td>HELLO 4</td>
        <td class="clickme">HELLO 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="finder"><td>96723234</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>HELLO</td>
        <td>HELLO 1</td>
        <td>HELLO 2</td>
        <td>HELLO 3</td>
        <td>HELLO 4</td>
        <td class="clickme">HELLO 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="finder"><td>756756</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.clickme').click(function() {
        $(this).parent('tr').next().toggle();
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Please ask any query if you have.

Have a good day.

Comment: Hi, sorry... The answer that you have provided does not match what I was looking for. I am looking for a PHP solution, not a jQuery one. I have updated my question to avoid confustion :-)